# What is a good base Xamarin Framework for a mobile App?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, frameworks, server

Hi I've just started a new job and the boss has asked me to find a "base Xamarin Framework" for a mobile app that need the following:

- Logging errors (log them locally and then push to a server)
- Clearly split Screen/UI stuff from backend stuff (i.e. calling a server or accessing a local database)
- Remembering state
- Holding user preferences (user settings)
- Dealing with timeouts when calling a server
- How navigation is managed

Not really sure how to go about finding one or what a good one is, any suggestions would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the almighty and beloved [MVVMCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross). It's widely used in the Xamarin community and it's constantly updated (it'll even have [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms) support)

It's a MVVM framework. It means it'll increase the amount of code you can share between your platforms and also make your code easier to maintain and understand due to the separations of concerns. If this is still not enough, it has a [lot of plugins](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins) that handle many of those tasks you mentioned and a lot more.

Comment: Awesome, checking it out now